# How to loop over different elements in a data frame in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with columns: device, value and condition. The condition column is a derived column based on a calculation off the value column. I have created this calculation in a for loop but I need the loop to reset for every device. How can I do this in pandas?

The logic for condition is something like this:

```
condition = False
condition_series = []
for row in df.iterrows():
        if row[1]['no_of_previous_rows_greater_than_threshold']==NUM_PREV_ROWS:
            condition = True
        if row[1]['value_greater_than_db_threshold']==False:
            condition = False
        condition_series.append(condition)
```

Appreciate the help!

```
device    value    condition
a           10        No
a           10        Yes
a           11        Yes
a           11        No
a           11        No
b           10        No
b           10        Yes
b           11        Yes
b           11        No
b           11        No
c           10        No
c           10        Yes
c           11        Yes
c           11        No
c           11        No
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `groupby` but you have left out a lot of details.  Please provide a [mcve] to reduce ambiguity and I'm sure people will be ready to help.

Comment: What is you condition which you used to create the `condition` column?

Comment: I have added in the logic for condition. Hope this helps.